# How to add sound to an onClick event in an Android application?

Tags: android, audio, onclicklistener

I want to be able to add a click sound whenever the uses taps a button in the application, any suggestions as to how I can make the behavior apply to the entire application ?
Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried [googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=Android+play+sound)?

Comment: Long/short sound? custom or from Android?

Comment: @dymmeh, I didn't find that on my first few hits, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the onClick of the button, add View.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK)

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) for more sophisticated setting (for example you can set the right and left volume values)

This is just an example:

```
private void playSound() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        SoundPool pl = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        // 5 indicates the maximum number of simultaneous streams for this SoundPool object

        int waterSound = pl.load(this, R.raw.water_sound_01, 0);
        // is the audio file I have imported in my project as resource

        pl.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                // The onLoadComplet method is called when a sound has completed loading.
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                soundPool.play(sampleId, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1);
                // second and third parameters indicates left and right value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
            }
        });
    }
```